# Capital "S" suddenly appears indented in Windows browsers - why?

Tags: windows, browser, rendering

We haven't found *anything anywhere* so far about that very strange effect.

For some time (don't know since when exactly), the capital S letter renders in Windows browsers like it's been moved by one or two pixels to the right. **This happens on many browsers, not just on my system, so our customer wants it repaired. It's not a question about local Windows configuration but about browser rendering.**

[image: Example for wrong rendering]

It can be seen here: http://www.holcimfoundation.org/T154/holcim_awards.htm

Here are some facts:

- **On Mac, Linux, Android and Windows with ClearType switched off the effect doesn't** occur
- **If zoomed in (CTRL+ on Firefox), the effect gets smaller and then disappears**
- It doesn't happen on every website, just a few - I believe I've seen this elsewhere too (but didn't keep the URLs)

We believe that this is a bug in the Windows font rendering engine. Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Or what kind of workaround we could use?

Comment: It looks ok on all my windows browsers (IE6, Chrome, FF4)

Comment: I know, it looks ok on many systems, but can be reproduced on many other as well. IE6 is old. Have you turned ClearType on?

Comment: I'd LOVE to know why people are suggesting to close that question! I think it's completely valid.

Comment: Because it belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: We'll it doesn't. I've tried to make that clear by editing the question. It is about HTML/CSS rendering and NOT about my personal computer.

Comment: Text rendering != programming

Comment: Microsoft released KB2545698 recently that adjusted hinting on some fonts at 8-10pt sizes. (A blog post with some information is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/06/29/ie9-cleartype-improved-clarity-for-tahoma-verdana-and-arial-fonts-fuzzy-blurry.aspx).) You may want to check and see if having that update correlates with the issue you're seeing. If that's the case, about all you could do would be to increase the font size.

Comment: @Olaf: I've just tried with Firefox 5.0 under WinXP. Admittedly, the 'S' is off so little that I maybe wouldn't have seen it, had you not told about it before. However, you're right, when you _know_ that it's there, it is indeed so disturbing that one can hardly bear it.

Comment: @Damon: it is, isn't it? Thanks, knowing someone (besides our customer) has the same feeling gives me some additional reassurance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On Mac, Linux, Android and Windows with ClearType switched off the effect doesn't

I'm not much of a ClearType wizard on Mac, Linux or Android but in Windows [you can tune it](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx).

> If zoomed in (CTRL+ on Firefox), the effect gets smaller and then disappears

To me this indicates that the text path is being rendered correctly but at 100% with so few pixels to work with the "mapping" is wrong. Do you have a problem with this at 72pt?

> We believe that this is a bug in the Windows font rendering engine

Do you have a reference rendering to compare this bug to? For all intents are purposes it could be by design, or your ClearType could be misconfigured.

**EDIT**:

I looked at this using the "Inspect Element" feature of Chrome. It seems you are trying to do too much with only 10 pixels of character real estate.

Observe the style and the rendering before:

[image: Chrome]

Now take bold off:

[image: Chrome]

Looks like it's not a bug, ClearType is doing the best it can with only 10 pixels.

Comment: This effect appears on many Windows installations around the world, so even if I can tune MY windows ClearType, there's absolutely no point to it - it'll still be seen by our customer and our customer's customers. And I think the difference between Windows with ClearType switched on vs. off can be regarded as reference.

Comment: ClearType off does not give a sub-pixel font rendering reference rendering. And I still can't see this being a problem when Windows has more than 8 pixels to render the S in. Try a bigger font. I have 4608000 pixels on my two work displays, use them.

Comment: It's a design that always worked, created by a graphics designer. We can't simply change that just because Windows seems to have a rendering problem it didn't have some time ago. They wouldn't like that.

Comment: "Do you have a problem with this at 72pt?" - Don't think so, haven't checked. Probably not. But still - it works on other OS's, used to work before - why not anymore?

Comment: Wow!! You put quite some effort into that question. And it clearly looks convincing. Thanks VERY much. The sad part still remains: Mac browsers render nicely as well and manage to get the S aligned. Anyway - I think the issue is clear now.

Comment: I think you mean "the issue is clear...type now". \*puts on sunglasses\*

Comment: :-D Lol! Yeah that's what I meant.